# download images to hard drive codeigniter php

Tags: image, codeigniter, download

I'm trying to download these images to hard drive but no luck using codeigniter download class and standard php

```
    <code>Click <a href="<?php echo base_url()."download";?>">HERE</a> To Download</code>
```

controller

```
function download (){
            $this->load->helper('download');

      $students =$this->db->get('students')->result();
$images=explode(',',$students->images );

                    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($images)-1;$i++){    
 //$path =  base_url().$images[$i];
         $data =get_file_contents( base_url().$images[$i]);
    $img = base_url().$images[$i];
                            $contents = explode('/', $img);
                            $name = "test.jpg";

    $download = force_download($name,$data);

}
```

it only outputs blank screen

Answer (score 0):

```
Click <a href="<?php echo base_url('controllerNameHere/download');?>">HERE</a> To Download
```

Please add your controller name before "download",inside the base_url(),in href.

In **Controller**:

```
file_get_contents(FCPATH . 'whereYourImageKept' . $image);
```

please put image path where you have kept your images.

And Please provide your **table** structure.

Comment: but would the href know which image each link will download one image, see the images belong to a user and in the users profile so should I put them in the same function as the users or i put them in a separate folder

Comment: show me the table structure so i can provide you answer in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

actully I did not need the function  after all all I have to do is putt the html download attribute to the href tag

```
    <code>Click <a href="<?php echo base_url().$images[$i] ;?>" download="<?php echo $name ?>">HERE</a> To Download</code>
```